# If I have the equation, $\frac{p}{K-p}=Ce^{rt}$, how can I solve for p?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is where I'm at:
$$
\frac{p}{(K-p)}=Ce^{rt}
$$
$$
p=(K-p)(Ce^{rt})
$$
$$
p=Ce^{rt}K-Ce^{rt}p
$$
$$
p+Ce^{rt}p=Ce^{rt}K
$$
$$
p(1+Ce^{rt})=Ce^{rt}K
$$
$$
p=\frac{Ce^{rt}K}{1+Ce^{rt}}
$$
Is it possible to simplify this further?

Comment: Your answer is just fine. There are lots of things you could do but none that would make it look any better. Though many would write $p=\frac{KC e^{rt}}{1+Ce^{rt}}$ just to keep all constants in front of exponentials, but this is not an error and is simply aesthetic.

Comment: Presumably in your problem it is known that $C\geq 0$ (or that $1+Ce^{rt}\neq 0$ on the domain).  When it is negative, $1+C e^{rt}$ will have a root, so you can't always divide by it.  A lot happens if $C<0$, though.  When $1+Ce^{rt}=0$, your next to last line becomes $0=-K$.  This then changes the original equation to $-1 = C e^{rt}$ ($p=0$ makes it undefined), which must hold for all $t$, so $C=-1$ and $r=0$, and the starting relation is just $-1=-1$.  In particular, $p$ is completely arbitrary, other than that it needs to be non-vanishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll include my comment as an answer just so I can demonstrate what I was referring to.

Comment:
Your answer is just fine. There are lots of things you could do but none that would make it look any better. Though many would write $p=\frac{KC e^{rt}}{1+Ce^{rt}}$ just to keep all constants in front of exponentials, but this is not an error and is simply aesthetic.

Ways you could 'simplfy', take out the $C$ from the top and from the bottom
$$
p=\frac{CK e^{rt}}{C(\frac{1}{C}+e^{rt})}=\frac{Ke^{rt}}{\frac{1}{C}+e^{rt}}
$$
or you could put the $e^{rt}$ into the denominator so only one exponential appears.
$$
p=\frac{KCe^{rt}}{1+Ce^{rt}}=\frac{KC}{e^{-rt}(1+Ce^{rt})}=\frac{KC}{1+Ce^{-rt}}
$$
The last one may be a bit cleaner, but many would argue that the exponential with a negative power should not appear in the denominator. So you see how thought there are things you can do, they don't necessarily simplify much (if anything). Your original answer seems clean enough as written.

Comment: What happened to the C in the denominator of the second simplification?

Comment: Indeed, it got lost in the typing. It is there now.